# Maximum possible distance between two vectors sampled from n-variate Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions

What would be the probability distribution of the distance between two vectors sampled from n-variate Gaussian distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: That would be $+\infty$.

Comment: That is true. I should rather ask expected distance in that case.

Comment: Oops wrong...I think expected distance will be 0.